# SwaggerUI auth redirect swaggerUiAuth of null

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to redirect a user if token doesn't exists in the cookie/localstorage.

I'm doing a check whether a token exist if not then redirect to http://authserver.webazure.net (e.g url).

```
if (cookieCheck == null) {
    window.location.href = 'http://authserver.webazure.net '; // redirect url
 } else {
  console.log('Cookie exist');
  // Omni auth
  window.swaggerUi.load();
  var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "Bearer " + $.cookie('access_token'), "header");
  window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("oauth2", apiKeyAuth);
}
```

Setting the cookie in o2c.html

```
if (window.opener.swaggerUiAuth.tokenUrl) // error is here
    window.opener.processOAuthCode(qp);
  else 
    window.opener.onOAuthComplete(qp);
    var accessToken = getUrlVars('access_token');
    setCookie('access_token', accessToken)
```

The redirect works okay however once Iogged in and and trying to redirect me back to my SwaggerUI I get an error 'Cannot read property 'swaggerUiAuth' of null'

Does anyone know about this?